# Error while executing MySQL Stored Procedure in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli, prepared-statement

I use this code for executing a MySQL Stored Procedure but this gives me unexpected result: 0 results.
If I execute the procedure **with same parameter** from my MySQL client this give me 2 results.

I use this PHP snippet:

```
  $_config_db_servername = "#";
  $_config_db_username = "#";
  $_config_db_password = "#";
  $_config_db_name = "#";
  $conn = new mysqli($_config_db_servername, $_config_db_username, $_config_db_password, $_config_db_name);

  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connessione al database fallita.");
  }

  $stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL aw_spZAAAOttieniDataTables(?);");
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $id_datatable);
  if($stmt->execute()) {
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if($result && $result->num_rows > 0) {
      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
      $dati[] = $row;
      $resp = new stdClass();
      $resp->esito = 1;
      $resp->dati = $dati;
    } else {
      $resp = new stdClass();
      $resp->esito = 20;
      $resp->dati = $dati;
    }
  } else {
    $resp = new stdClass();
    $resp->esito = 30;
    $resp->dati = $dati;
  }


  $stmt->close();
  $conn->close();
```

Result is:

```
{"esito":20,"dati":[]}
```

From the client the result is:

[image: Text]

Dump of the result is:

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(1) }
```

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'c4_awuser'@'%'
PROCEDURE c4_awdb.aw_spZAAAOttieniDataTables(IN _identificativoTabella VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

  DECLARE finito INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE nomeColonna VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE titoloColonna VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE queryColonne LONGTEXT DEFAULT 'SELECT ';
  DECLARE _nomeVista VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE curColonne CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
      COLUMN_NAME,
      COALESCE(nome_campo, COLUMN_NAME) AS nome_campo
    FROM information_schema.columns
    LEFT JOIN aw_tbZAAEGestioneTabelleDati
      ON ZAAEcvVistaAssociata = _nomeVista
    LEFT JOIN aw_tbZAACCampi
      ON nome_campo_db = COLUMN_NAME
      AND tabella = ZAAEcvNomeTabella
    WHERE table_name = _nomeVista;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finito = 1;

  SELECT
    ZAAEcvVistaAssociata INTO _nomeVista
  FROM aw_tbZAAEGestioneTabelleDati
  WHERE ZAAEcvIdentificativoTabella = _identificativoTabella;

  IF _nomeVista IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT
      DISTINCT 1
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name = _nomeVista) THEN

    OPEN curColonne;

    ciclaColonne: LOOP
        FETCH curColonne INTO nomeColonna,titoloColonna;
        IF finito = 1 THEN 
          LEAVE ciclaColonne;
        END IF;

        SET queryColonne = CONCAT(queryColonne,nomeColonna,' AS \'',titoloColonna,'\',');

    END LOOP ciclaColonne;

    CLOSE curColonne;

    IF RIGHT(queryColonne,1) = ',' THEN
        SET queryColonne = LEFT(queryColonne,LENGTH(queryColonne)-1);
    END IF;

    SET queryColonne = CONCAT(queryColonne,' FROM ',_nomeVista,';');

    SET @s = queryColonne;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;

  END IF;

END
```

I pass as parameter an id such as 'elenco_corsi'. I search in aw_tbZAAEGestioneTabelleDati what is his view, then I use system table to get view's field, the i build a query and execute it via statement.

Comment: Have you tried debugging out exactly what your script ends up sending and compared it to what you’re doing in the client?

Comment: @iJamesPHP2 sure, I print the variable right before using it in bind_param, then I use it in the client

Comment: Ever heard of while loop?

Comment: @u_mulder this doen't solve my problem. In my case 1 record should be returned - not 0 (I tried simplify as much as possible)

Comment: Then dump what does get_result returns.

Comment: @u_mulder dump: object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(1) }

Comment: I suppose this https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php should help somehow.

Comment: What is the output of `$result->fetch_assoc()`? Are you getting any values? Why do you use `$result->num_rows`?

Comment: @Dharman my code doesn't enter in fetch_assoc loop because $result->num_rows is 0, but this should'n be 0...

Comment: Why are you using `$result->num_rows`?

Comment: @Dharman maybe for knowing the number of the results? What should I use?

Comment: Where do you defined `$id_datatable`?

Comment: Also, enable mysqli error reporting [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: @Dharman that is a GET parameter, I also tried setting it fixed in code. Now after execute the sp it takes about 20 seconds and then "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

Comment: Do you have a debugger installed? Fire it up and go line by line through the code. For us here there are many unknowns to debug it for you.

Comment: @Dharman I don't know if this can help you, in my sp I have dynamic SQL. I try setting fixed code (not dynamic) in sp and it seems ok. I have updated my original question so you can see sp code.